# VHD with no boot signature 55AA

Tags: boot, mbr, vhd, vhdx

I have a VHD sample which does not have the mbr boot signature of 55AA at offset of 510.Usually when I am creating VHD sample on Windows 10 using diskmgmt, it is assigning this boot signature as soon as disk is initialised to either MBR or GPT. So, what exactly is the reason for the sample, that it is missing this boot signature.

Although when I try to extract this sample using any 3rd party tool, it correctly extracts the contents of this sample VHD.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? A VHD can hold arbitrary contents, just like a physical storage device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It might simply have been removed deliberately (e.g. to confuse you).
2. It might have been created using a different tool that doesn't consider the boot signature necessary. For GPT-partitioned disks that aren't meant to be bootable on a BIOS system, the MBR in sector 0 may as well just not exist. (Though the EFI specification says it should be there, it's not *used* for anything.)
3. It might be entirely unpartitioned – i.e. neither MBR nor GPT but with a filesystem starting directly at sector 0 (aka "superfloppy mode"). While sector 0 of some filesystems looks similar to the MBR sector, that's not necessarily true for all of them.